# PHP Mailer doesn't send the mail yet returns no error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I m trying to use PHP mailer using one of my Gmail accounts to send emails, but for some reason, it has no errors in console, returns success back but doesn't send mail as well.

FYI, I have checked other related questions in the stack that are similar to me, but still feel I need expert advice on it.

**Index :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Send an Email</title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <h4 class="sent-notification"></h4>

        <form id="myForm">
            <h2>Send an Email</h2>

            <label>Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
            <br><br>

            <label>Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email">
            <br><br>

            <label>Subject</label>
            <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder=" Enter Subject"> 
            <br><br>

            <p>Message</p>
            <textarea id="body" rows="5" placeholder="Type Message"></textarea>
            <br><br>

            <button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send An Email">Submit</button> 
        </form>
    </center>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
            var name = $("#name");
            var email = $("#email");
            var subject = $("#subject");
            var body = $("#body");

            if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject) && isNotEmpty(body)) {
                $.ajax({
                   url: 'sendEmail.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {
                       name: name.val(),
                       email: email.val(),
                       subject: subject.val(),
                       body: body.val()
                   }, success: function (response) {
                        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                        $('.sent-notification').text("Message Sent Successfully.");
                   }
                });
            }
        }

        function isNotEmpty(caller) {
            if (caller.val() == "") {
                caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
                return false;
            } else
                caller.css('border', '');

            return true;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**sendEmail.php**

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

        require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        //SMTP Settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "harishkolliparat@gmail.com"; //enter you email address
        $mail->Password = '*****'; //enter you email password
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        

        //Email Settings
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->addAddress("harishkolliparat@gmail.com"); //enter you email address
        $mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
        $mail->Body = $body;

        if ($mail->send()) {
            $status = "success";
            $response = "Email is sent!";
        } else {
            $status = "failed";
            $response = "Something is wrong: <br><br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

        exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
    }
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're running an old and [vulnerable](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-11358/) version of jQuery; update it.

Comment: As I'm sure you know from all the other questions you read, `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` will show you what the server is saying and allow you to confirm that it's sending correctly. Beyond that, you're using gmail, so your messages are probably in a spam folder.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried to use XDebug?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable debug for it to spit out the details of the sent email. Note that once debug mode is turned on, it still outputs data, a whole lot of email data about the sending process whether it fails or succeeds.

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` disables debug

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` enables client related debug

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` enables server related debug

Your debug statement should come before any of the other `$mail` object statements, that is before your `$mail->isSMTP()` call

Comment: added that before isSMTP(), but this time, i not even receiving the message sent message , and it give no error in console as well

Comment: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` is fairly useless for debugging as it only shows you what the client is saying. `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` will show you what the server is saying (the most useful part), and `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` will give additional connection information.

Comment: Thanks for the complete information @Synchro I'll edit my answer